# Is it possible to set actions call a function at default pagination of v-data-table?

Tags: datatable, pagination, action, vuetify.js

I would like to call a function when I click the previous button, next button and the rowsPerPage numbers are changed.

Is it possible to use default v-data-table pagination when I use actions-prepend slot? 
I tried but it seems not working.

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="alertList"
    :pagination.sync="pagination"
    :rows-per-page-items="pagination.rowsPerPageItems"
    :total-items="pagination.totalCount"
    :loading="paginationLoading"
    class="elevation-1 block_display"
  >
    <template v-slot:items="props">
      <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.id }}</td>
       ...
    </template>
    <template v-slot:actions-prepend>  // add another button before the default pagination
      <v-btn @click='goPrev'> < </btn>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
   ....
  },
  methods: {
    goPrev() {
      // want to call vuex actions
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can use `hide-action` option and `v-pagination` component

Comment: @Toodoo Thank you. But I would like to use the default style but `v-pagination` 's style is different. Is there options for the style?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer which would be better or not.

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="alertList"
    :pagination.sync="cstPagination"
    :rows-per-page-items="pagination.rowsPerPageItems"
    :total-items="pagination.totalCount"
    :loading="paginationLoading"
    class="elevation-1 block_display"
  >
    <template v-slot:items="props">
      <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.id }}</td>
       ...
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
   ....
  },
  computed: {
    get() {
      return this.pagination   // props
    },
    set(val) {
        // val: changed pagination value
    }
  }
}
</script>
```